# SSIS- ADODB Recordset Error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi, ssis-2016

I am getting below error while running my ssis package.

> Error: COM error object information is available.  Source: "ADODB.Recordset"  error code: 0x800A0BCD  Description: "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.".

I am storing a value in an object variable using RecordSetDestination. And I am passing the object variable in 3 ForEachLoop containers and I am trying to run it parallel. If one of the container is passed then the rest of them getting failed.

[image]

Below is the same configuraiton in all 3 ForEachLoop's

[image]

[image]

Any property needs to change or object variable need to rest or we can't use the object variable for parallel exec in ForEach ADO Enumerator.

Need your input here... Thanks

Comment: Try to run Foreach Loops sequentially. Looks like one of the FE Loops locks the recordset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the variable for the recordset.
The first option would be you add three data flows like origins pointing each one to a different variable.
The second is adding a multicast in your initial data flow, with three outputs, each one pointing to a different variable.
Then you go to each Foreach Loop Container and set the respective variable in the Enumerator configurarion section.

Answer (score 0):

As Ferdipux proposed, try to run Foreach Loops sequentially. This worked for me.